# Closest number between two lists within a given tolerance

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have two large list with numbers such as:

`list1={number1,number2,number3..........etc} list2={number1,number2,number3..........etc}`

**Question:**

How can I find the number or numbers that are the closest between the two list within a given tolerance?.

As an example with two short lists, if I have something like list1={1,2,3,4,5} and list2={5.5,6,15,20,30} and my tolerance is 0.5, then the numbers would be "5" (from list 1) and "5.5" (from list 2). If my tolerance was 1, then the numbers would be "5"(from list 1) and "5.5" and "6" (from list 2) and so on.

Comment: Try `f[x_,y_]:=If[Abs[x-y]<=tolerance,{x,y}]; Outer[f,list1,list2]` and see what you get. That isn't the complete answer, but it gives you something to start with and think about how to get where you want to go.

Comment: @Bill thank you very much for this!. It is a very interesting approach. When there is no operation within the tolerance it gives me "Null". Is there anyway to remove the output of "Null" that it gives and only see the the number it gives?

Comment: Yes that is what I had seen. `Null` is what `If` returns when your test is false. It wasn't clear to me what form you wanted to put the results into. So I thought that you could look at this and see if you could figure out how you could modify and use this. If you just want rid of the `Null` you could try `DeleteCases[%,Null,Infinity]` which will remove `Null` no matter how deeply it is inside other lists. Does this help? Can you figure out what the next step is?

Comment: @Bill thank you very much. This is a great input! I appreciate it !

Comment: As a variation of @Bill's suggestion, I would use the result of `DistanceMatrix[list1,list2]` to reckon out which numbers to keep.